# In Bacau, Romania, what is the current name of the street that used to be called "Filimon Sirbu"?

Tags: romania, locate-this, nostalgia

My mother immigrated from Romania 55 years ago. Now she wants to travel back for sight-seeing, but all the names have been changed. The name of the street she grew up on was Filimon Sirbu. How can we locate its current name? Bacau municipal services were not very responsive.

Comment: IMHO the question is on-topic: I read a travelling intention in it, similar to the various other [tag:locate-this] questions we have.

Comment: 100% on-topic. No doubt about that.

Comment: If you think a question doesn't belong here if you don't think many people care about the answer, it's time you familiarized yourself with the [Joel Spolsky / Stack Exchange concept of "the long tail"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/). Travelling back to your ancestral home is travelling.

Answer (score 8):

According to [this PDF document](http://www.primariabacau.ro/fisiere/pagini_fisiere/nomenclator_stradal_2014.pdf) from the official site of the hall of Bacau the new name of the *Filimon Sirbu* street is **GEORGE BACOVIA**.

I do not speak Romanian, but google translate says that "Denumire veche" means "old name". Also, it seems that this street had a few other old names beside Filimon Sirbu: "Gimnaziu", "Regina Maria" and "Calea Moinesti".

Here is the street in [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Strada+George+Bacovia,+Bac%C4%83u,+Romania/@46.5694156,26.9037197,17z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x40b56fded37a8643:0x13b3307d62cf48d7), perhaps an aerial view helps your mom in recognizing it.

Comment: If not from an aerial view, certainly the mother should recognise it from [streetview](https://goo.gl/maps/6DpfgYbrNHJJF4Ac8) :)